# Question about spatial uniformity of particle density in plasmas (from Bellan)

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

Early in [Bellan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521528003) he asks us to consider a finite-temperature plasma and assume that the ion and electron densities are initially equal and spatially uniform. He approaches the problem of calculating the Debye length by considering each species of particle, $\sigma$, as being a fluid so that the equation of motion for each species (after some approximations and assumptions) is

$0\approx -n_{\sigma}q_{\sigma}\nabla\phi-\nabla P_{\sigma}$

where $P_{\sigma}=\kappa T_{\sigma} n_{\sigma}$ which because we assumed that the temperature is spatially uniform gives us

$0\approx -n_{\sigma}q_{\sigma}\nabla\phi-\kappa T_{\sigma}\nabla n_{\sigma}$

But didn't we also assume that $n_{\sigma}$ was also spatially uniform? Why then are we taking a gradient of it?

It seems to me like what we have done is develop an operator

$-q_{\sigma}\nabla \phi - \kappa T_{\sigma}\nabla$

and used it to look for homogeneous solutions of the species density but I am still confused as to why we are taking a gradient of a quantity that we assumed to be spatially uniform and I hope that one of you good people will have some insight

Comment: The Debye length is on short enough length scales to assume that the particles behave in an isothermal manner, i.e., temperature is constant over that scale.  Generally the Debye length is the smallest relevant scale length in non-quantum/quark plasmas and all things varying below the Debye length are not physically meaningful for most applications.  The whole point of the derivation is to show that the electric fields will be screened out over length scales larger than some characteristic length scale, called the Debye length.